# Yii 2 Get NULL when select data with where in array

Tags: mysql, arrays, yii2

I have an array **$areaID** :

```
array(3) {
 [0]=> array(1) { ["idarea"]=> int(56) } 
 [1]=> array(1) { ["idarea"]=> int(67) } 
 [2]=> array(1) { ["idarea"]=> int(116)} 
}
```

Then, I want to select from MySQL database to get data where **$areaID** in array. My query:

```
$data = (new \yii\db\Query())
                    ->select('*')
                    ->from('store')
                    ->join('LEFT JOIN','detail_area','detail_area.idareaV = store.idareas')
                    ->join('LEFT JOIN','detail_user','detail_user.id_area = detail_area.idarea')
                    ->where(['in','detail_area.idarea',$areaID])
                    ->all()
```

But when running,, i got my $areaID is null. Like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `store` LEFT JOIN `detail_area` ON detail_area.idareaV = store.idareas LEFT JOIN `detail_user` ON detail_user.id_area = detail_area.idarea WHERE (`detail_area`.`idarea` IN (NULL, NULL, NULL))
```

Can you help me? Thank you ...

Comment: do you have nested array ?

Comment: i don't have @YasinPatel

Comment: array(3) {
 [0]=> array(1) { ["idarea"]=> int(56) } 
 [1]=> array(1) { ["idarea"]=> int(67) } 
 [2]=> array(1) { ["idarea"]=> int(116)} 
}

Comment: this is nested array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
->where([
    'detail_area.idarea' => array_values(
        \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($areaID, 'idarea', 'idarea')
    )
])
```